# App service managed certificate for a naked domain

Tags: ssl-certificate, domain, certificate

I've successfully created certificates (App service managed certificate) for other custom domains (for example [www.cortoso.com](http://www.cortoso.com), cortoso.com, [www.cortoso.cz](http://www.cortoso.cz), cortoso.cz, ...). However, I am unable to create a certificate for cortoso.co.uk and cortoso.com.pl even though other naked domains work ([www.cortoso.co.uk](http://www.cortoso.co.uk), [www.cortoso.com.pl](http://www.cortoso.com.pl) works too).

*Error: "Hostname not eligible for App Service Managed Certificates creation. ..."*

I am using DNS Zone and the appropriate CNAME record is present the same way for the other domains which work.

I know the feature is in preview (for apex domains) and the issue only stands for the two mentioned (cortoso.com.pl, cortoso.co.uk). Do I have to treat those two in some special way? I can provide my own certificate but I would rather not mix them with others.

Any input, insight, or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this issue for myself. I wanted to migrate from an unmanaged SSL certificate, to an Azure Managed Certificate for a naked/apex domain (eg mydomain.com), but was getting the same error as this question.

I fixed it by deleting and immediately re-creating the custom domain, together with the old binding in the Custom Domain's tab of Azure's web app blade for my app.  When recreating the domain, you can opt to create a new managed certificate, whereby validation will pass - and may ask you to add validation to the DNS management of your domain registrar.